# Send multiple POST requests to URL Objective-C

Tags: iphone, post

I'm trying to make an app that posts data to the URL http://api.sourcelair.com/exec/create and it needs the data to be sent with post.

This is the data that needs to be sent to the URL

```
    code      : "The source code that you want to execute" ,
    language  : "The programming language of your code (e.g. C)"
    input     : "The optional standard input of your program"
```

What would be the code that I could send the data to the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using a Library such as `ASIHTTPRequest` It would be as simple as:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"The source code that you want to execute" forKey:@"code"];
[request setPostValue:@"The programming language of your code (e.g. C)" forKey:@"language"];
[request setPostValue:@"The optional standard input of your program" forKey:@"input"];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Of course you would need to set the delegate, and the response methods. You can find more information on `ASIHTTPRequest` here, http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Alternatively, you can use `NSURLConnection` class to make `POST` requests. More information here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html